# Nginx as a Reverse Proxy for Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, google-cloud-platform

In fact,I have two Wordpress instances that are started in two different apache web-servers, as well as each instance has a different IP address.

[Image description(Please look at her)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj0Me.png)

I installed Nginx in the first machine (Machine 1).Nginx will play the role of a reverse proxy,he is started on port 80 and apache on port 8080 , the logic that I wanted to apply it this the following :

1. If the user accesses in the first machine ( to M1.com ), Nginx will receive the request and it will redirect the request to apache which is booting on port 8080 in the first machine (Already implemented)
2. If the user enters a url for example (M1.com/m2) , he accesses to wordpress instance which is started in the machine 2 , but the domain name must not be changed , ti must remain on the same domain name (M1.com)

If someone can help me or give me an idea on how I can implement this logic I will be very grateful

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ should probably be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the location block in nginx configuration. For example:

```
location /m2 {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
                proxy_pass http://machine2-ip$uri$is_args$args;
        }
```

The above configuration block will forward all url requests starting with m2 to the proxy server with ip machine2-ip

Comment: **Thank you Nadir, it's work fine ,  I am really grateful to have an instant reply from you. Stay blessed dear**